# Average value of the function $f(x)=\cos^{2}x$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: integration, functions

What exactly is the average value of the function $f(x)=\cos^{2}x$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$? Of course, we assume that the function is integrable on this interval, then we can use the average value theorem $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2xdx$. I'm not sure about this but is the final value $\frac{3\pi}{4}$? This seems reasonable enough as it is kind of an inflection point.

Comment: Can you do better than *assuming* that the function is integrable on this interval? Can you prove it?

Comment: Also how did you get the value $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$? I just did it myself and did not get that. Could you show your working?

Comment: Since $\cos ^2x=\frac12+\frac12\cos2x$, the average should be $\frac12$

Comment: @PatrickStevens Well the function is continuous so it is therefore integrable. The only thing I need to prove is its continuity, which is omitted here.

Comment: Thank you @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints (especially good if you do not have trigonometric identities at hand):

1. Note that $\cos^2(x) = \cos(x) * \cos(x)$
2. Use integration by parts twice to get an expression of the form $\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2(x) \mathrm{d}x = \ldots$ by using $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x)$.
3. The final value of the average is $1/2$.

Can you take it from here?

Alternatively, you can use the trigonometric identity that Hagen von Eitzen posted in the comments.